# Printing in unexpected order

Tags: arrays, perl

I expected the following to print in the order of the elements of `@Data`, but it's printing in the order of the elements of `@Queries`. Am I missing something? I also tried declaring the items to be printed after `foreach(@data){...` and then printing inside that loop, but still wrong order.

`$datafile` is a file with the following:

```
GR29929,JAMES^BOB
GR21122,HANK^REN
```

`$queryfile` is a file with the following:

```
(3123123212):# FD  [GR21122]
line 2
line 3
line 4
(12): # FD         [HANK^REN]
line 6
line 7
line 8
(13): # FD           [Y]
-------------------------------
--------------------------------
(3123123212):# FD  [GR29929]
line 2
line 3
line 4
(12): #  FD       [JAMES^BOB]
line 6
line 7
line 8
(13): # FD           [Z]
```

The output file is:

```
GR21122,HANK^WREN,Y
GR29929,JAMES^BOB,Z
```

When I want:

```
GR29929,JAMES^BOB,Z    
GR21122,HANK^WREN,Y
```

Code is:

```
open(DA, "<$datafile");
open(QR, "<$queryfile");
my @Data = <DA>;
my @Queries = <QR>;
foreach (@Data) {
    my ( $acce, $namee ) = split( ',', $_ );
    chomp $acce;
    chomp $namee;
    print "'$acce' and '$namee'\n";

    for my $i ( 0 .. $#Queries ) {
        my $Qacce = $Queries[$i];
        my $Qname = $Queries[ $i + 4 ];
        my $Gen   = $Queries[ $i + 8 ];

        if ( $Qacce =~ m/$acce/ and $Qname =~ m/$namee/ ) {
            my ($acc) = $Qacce =~ /\[(.+?)\]/;
            my ($gen) = $Gen =~ /\[(.+?)\]/;
            $gen =~ s/\s+$//;
            my ($name) = $Qname =~ /\[(.+?)\]/;

            print GL "$i,$acc,$gen,$name\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code prints all the queries that match the first data, then it prints all the queries that match the second data, etc. That sounds like what you want. But your question could be clearer. Could you provide a minimal runnable demonstration of the problem. Don't forget to say what output you expect (not just some imprecise description).

Comment: Your updated code snippet is incomplete, it doesn't show how the files are read and the arrays are populated. We still can't help you fix it without substantial guesswork.

Comment: You show appropriate contents of your data files and describe the problem clearly, so this would have been a very satisfactory question if you had posted your real code, which doesn't work at all as it stands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic shell of your program prints what you ask for, but there is a lot missing. The refactoring below should do what you want.

You had a problem with the values of your `$i` index variable, so that the first time around the loop you were accessing `@data` elements `[0, 4, 8]`, the second time `[1, 5, 9]` etc. It looks like the second loop execution should use elements `[11, 15, 19]` and so on. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

In addition you were using regular expressions to compare the keys in the two files, and you were finding nothing because the name values contain caret `^` characters which are special within regexes. Escaping the strings using `\Q...\E` fixed this.

Note that a better solution would use hashes to match keys across the two files, but without details on your file format - particularly `queryfile` - I have had to follow your own algorithm.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my ($data_file, $query_file) = qw/ datafile.txt queryfile.txt /;

my @queries = do {
  open my $query_fh, '<', $query_file;
  <$query_fh>;
};
chomp @queries;

open my $data_fh,  '<', $data_file;

while (<$data_fh>) {
  chomp;
  my ($acce, $namee) = split /,/;

  for (my $i = 0; $i < @queries; $i += 11) {
    my ($qacce, $qname, $qgen) = @queries[$i, $i+4, $i+8];

    if ( $qacce =~ /\Q$acce\E/ and $qname =~ /\Q$namee\E/ ) {
      my ($acc, $name, $gen) = map / \[ ( [^\[\]]+ ) \] /x, ($qacce, $qname, $qgen);
      $gen =~ s/\s+\z//;

      print "$acc,$name,$gen\n";
    }
  }
}
```

**output**

```
GR29929,JAMES^BOB,Z
GR21122,HANK^REN,Y
```

Comment: although the latter is less efficient, don't `for (my $i = 0; $i < @queries; $i += 11) {` and `for my $i ( 0 .. $#Queries ) {` ultimately produce the same output? Eventually it will get to the correct spot, although it may take 11 times longer. I think that what was missing from my original script was `/\Q$namee\E/` ($acce should not contain special characters), and when I make that change it works. I'm very interested in your script, though; it has taught me better ways to do what I am doing--thanks.

Comment: In terms of the hash solution: I'm having trouble understanding how it would be done without iterating through the hashes similarly to the arrays; to me, it just seemed like I would be essentially doing the same thing but with structures that are more unfamiliar